# Make a sepecific button load in JSON state react using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 buttons which are rendered from a loop over an array and rendered in react.

The 3 buttons are represented in a state as follows:

```
const [buttonLoading, setButtonLoading] = UseSafeState({
    free: { is_loading: false },
    starter: { is_loading: false },
    professional: { is_loading: false },
})
```

***(UseSafeState is just a hook component that do exactly the same thing as useState, but safely)***

I would like that by clicking on one of the buttons, a loader is displayed on this specific button while waiting for the end of a request.

I created this test component to shorten my code and test.
What I'm trying to do here is display the loader on the button that is clicked relative to its name.

```
export default function Test() {
    const [buttonLoading, setButtonLoading] = UseSafeState({
        free: { is_loading: false },
        starter: { is_loading: false },
        professional: { is_loading: false },
    })
    
    // To set the is_loading property of the specific key of the json state
    const changeButtonLoading = (type, isLoading) => {
        const buttonLoadingChanged = buttonLoading
        buttonLoadingChanged[type].is_loading = isLoading

        setButtonLoading(buttonLoadingChanged)
    }

    const BUTTONS = [
        { name: 'free', label: 'FREE' },
        { name: 'starter', label: 'STARTER' },
        { name: 'professional', label: 'PROFESIONAL' },
    ]

    return BUTTONS.map((button, key) => {
        return (
            <Button key={key} onClick={() => changeButtonLoading(button.name, true)}>
                {buttonLoading[button.name].is_loading ? <LoaderButton /> : button.label}
            </Button>
        )
    })
}
```

***(LoaderButton /> component is just a basic loader with some css and html)***

But the problem is that when I click on one of the button, he don't display the loader. But he display it if I modify something in my code to force a render.

Comment: you are mutating the object, but the reference remains the same, try changing the reference it should work.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by the reference ?

Comment: setButtonLoading(buttonLoadingChanged) -> after this, your state structure is not preserved.

Comment: a javascript object reference, I think the below answer solves it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const changeButtonLoading = (type, isLoading) => {
  setButtonLoading(prev => {
    return {
      ...prev,
      [type] : {is_loading : isLoading}
     }
  })
};
```

Comment: It also doesn't work

Comment: have you tried after my edit ? Variable names could be wrong... Preserve your old state and change what you NEED to change. you are OVERRIDING your state completely.

Comment: Yep I change it by myself, but with this code even after made a re-render the button does not load anymore unlike mine which loads the button after a re render

Comment: Oups my bad ! It's work correctly ! I took the liberty of removing the second is_loading after the colon thinking it would be the same thing, but your code works perfectly. Thank you !

Comment: Phew... Good to know.